# backbone/marioneete: templateHelpers not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I find that when using templateHelpers and set it as a function, it is not displaying at all.

But when I use a variable inside the templateHelper, it is displaying. Basically what they have in this link https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.view.md#viewevents, it is not working on my end.

The jsfiddle is in here http://jsfiddle.net/gerlstar/Ms7uN/2/

```
model2 = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        age: '',
        name: ''
    },
    initialize: function () {
        this.set({
            name: "Terry"
        });
    }

});

someview = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: "div",
    template: "#tpl-box",
    templateHelpers: {
        showMessage: function () {
            return " is the coolest!";
        }
    }
});

var app = new Marionette.Application();
app.container = new Backbone.Marionette.Region({
    el: "#container"
});
app.layout = new Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
    template: "#tpl-layout",
    region: {
        rgn: "#rgn1"
    }
});
var m = new model2();
var view2 = new someview({
    model: m
});

app.on("initialize:after", function() {

layout = new app.layout();
app.container.show(layout);
layout.rgn.show(view2);
});
app.start();
```

HTML

```
<div id="container" class="container"></div>
<script id="tpl-box" type="text/html">
    <%= name %>
</script>
<script id="tpl-layout" type="text/html">
    < h3 > My layout < /h3>
        <div id="rgn1">
        </div >
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is your fixed fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pSv9h/

### You had two problem:

#### 1. `new` keyword when defining your layout,

You shouldn't use the `new` keyword when extending a backbone/marionnete class.

`app.layout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend` instead of `app.layout = new Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend`

#### 2. `regions` not `region`

You need to define your regions inside of `regions` not `region`

Comment: thank you! But the jsfiddle is not working as expected. The tempalateHelpers are not displaying. http://jsfiddle.net/pSv9h/1/